# How to execute a function with specified param inside of socket.io connection function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, callback

I need some help with callbacks in my node.js app. Im working with socket.io to emit the data. I need to create a function with an emit and specific param that is being calculated outside of io.on('connection') brackets. I need to fire that inner function only when i calculate the param later in my app. How can i do that?

Example code:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    function name(param)
    {
        socket.emit('name', param);
    }
    //rest of the socket.io code
}

//function that calculates the param to be executed above^
function()
{
    var param = somevalue;
    //How can i execute function that is in io.on brackets and pass the param to it from here?
}
```

Comment: Can't you return the value when calling the function back to your .on event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // 10 is "param" in Hello
    Hello(10, function(result){
        console.log("Result from Hello function: " + result);

        // you have still access to socket

    });
}

function Hello(param, callback)
{
    // code etc
    var result = param + 1;

    callback(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the return value of `io` to a variable and use it to emit events when needed. Something like this:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect', function(){});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){});

io.on('event', (socket) => {
    getParam();
}

function name(param) {
    socket.emit('name', param);
}

function getParam()
{
    var param = somevalue;
    name(param);
}
```

Comment: The thing is that i want to fire the inner function later after other events happens. The code that determines when to execute the inner function is outside of io.on brackets.

Comment: In that case, you can create the `name` function outside and call it from your other function whenever needed.

Comment: I don't have access to socket.emit outside of io.on connection scope as far as i know.

Comment: Agree with @PrerakSola 's answer. Also, and i do not have a way to test it right know, maybe you can send 'socket ' as a parameter to that function that will do the calculation and use it to emit your values... not sure though.

Comment: Im on the server-side, so everything i do i need to do inside of io.on('connection', (socket) => { }

am i right?

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function from your `.on`event like this:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    var calculatedParam = calParam(param); //Assuming param exists in the current context...
    socket.emit('name', calculatedParam);
    //rest of the socket.io code
}

//function that calculates the param to be executed above^
function calParam(p)
{
    var calcP = p; //Obviously calculate something here...
    return calcP;
}
```

Comment: I need that socket.emit() to be in a function so i can execute it later at specific time but code that determines when is outside of this scope.

Comment: mmm can you provide more context? Are you going to make some asynchronous call to get that param and the 'emit' the value?

Comment: No, i just need to be able to call this inner function later and pass a param which is a number so i can emit the changes on the site.